# Jersey /Grizzly Server start block until all resources loaded

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, grizzly

In Jersey with a Grizzly server was wondering whether there is a way to make the HttpServer start block until all resources have been loaded ?

eg, I do this to start the server

> HttpServer httpServer =
>   GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(base_uri), rc);

But my ResourceConfig loads some heavyweight objects that themselves take a while to load.  I want to block until all these resources are loaded and only start the server properly after this.  Is there a built in way to do it via the grizzly/jersey apis ?

Or do I have to roll my own - perhaps whereby my individual resources register themselves somewhere else and I monitor that and only start the server when they're all done.

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Hmm, I thought the resources are loaded in the same thread we start Grizzly HttpServer, so we always start HttpServer after resources are loaded. Isn't it the case?

Comment: After the server starts, it doesn't block waiting for the underlying resources to be fully initialised.  Or so it seems.  The resource class in question has to load a lot of data before it's completely initialised.  I can see that the server starts before this initialisation is complete.  So perhaps the resources are loaded, but themselves not initialised completely.  I'd like to be able to block until all resources are fully initialised.

Comment: can you figure out in what thread the resources are initialized?